# The authorized of DHCP server failed with Error Code : 20079

Tags: authorization, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp

I want to install DHCP and in the configuration process :
[image]

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference for anyone who may search for this.
I solved this on our server by;
Load the DHCP snap-in and 'Unauthorized' the server.
Restarted, the DHCP service (All Tasks>Restart).
Then 'Authorized' the server.
Back in the Server Manager, refresh the server, the notification was then resolved.